# Removing duplicates in Google Sheets (script) taking too long to process

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, duplicates

I am trying to have my entire sheet deduped and the script works fine however, it takes 60+ seconds to run. Am I over complicating this and really there is a simpler code to get what I need? It just seems like a long time to process such a simple task.

My data is only between 4-12k rows.

```
function removeDuplicates() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[1];
 var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
 var newData = [];
 for (var i in data) {
   var row = data[i];
   var duplicate = false;
   for (var j in newData) {
    if (row.join() == newData[j].join()) {
     duplicate = true;
    }
  }
//If not a duplicate, put in newData array
 if (!duplicate) {
  newData.push(row);
 }
}
//Delete the old Sheet and insert the newData array
 sheet.clearContents();
 sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: I don’t know the Google Sheets API.

I suggested a few improvements and added the comments in the code.
A big thing in performance is caching. So don’t do things twice if not necessary (or DRY = Don’t repeat yourself!).
If you forget your wallet and have to go upstairs again, it doubles the time taking you to leave the front door. Same with code.

If you are generally interested in performance boosts (and everyone should be) I suggest you to take a look at [How to write Performant JavaScript- Mark Nadal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BEqH-oZ4UXI)

```
function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[1];
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = [];
  var newDataJoinedCache = {};

  // help the loop to not have to read the same values over and over again
  // if you prepare as much data as possible for the loop it will thankfully speed up
  for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    // data won’t change in the loop, so we can cache it here once(!)
    // as you can see, I added a semicolon to prevent unwanted results
    // imagine a row with colums [ "a", "bc"] and another one with [ "ab", "c"]
    // just joined without separator they will both be the same "abc", which is wrong
    var joinedRow = data[i].join(";");

    // no need as we will know it with one simple comparison
    // var duplicate = false;

    // Just make one simple comparison
    // instead of over and over joining the arrays in newData just cache them

    if (!newDataJoinedCache[joinedRow]) {
      newData.push(data[i]);
      // we push the joined string as a cache
      newDataJoinedCache[joinedRow] = true;
    }
  }
  //Delete the old Sheet and insert the newData array
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

Let me know how it works out and how much time this will save in comparison.

Comment: It went from 60+ seconds to about an average of 10-15 seconds... some were 3-4 seconds. That's awesome! Thanks for your insight!

Comment: Glad to hear 

Answer (score 1):

If you use an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects), you'll dramatically lower the number of iterations.

```
function removeDuplicates() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  let newDataObject = {};
  for (let row of data) {
    newDataObject[row.join()] = row;
  }
  const newData = Object.values(newDataObject);
  
  // Clear the old Sheet and insert the newData array
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As other approach, how about using the method of `removeDuplicates()`? When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function removeDuplicates() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[1].getDataRange().removeDuplicates();
}
```

#### Reference:

- [removeDuplicates()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#removeduplicates)

Answer (score 0):

Now that we have V8 you can use the [**`Set`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) class. Didn't make any attempts to benchmark performance so I don't know if you'll fair any better where speed of execution is concerned, code is far more readable though. Try the following and tell me how it goes:

```js
// V8 runtime version using Set
function removeDuplicates(sheetName) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
    var rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

    var dedupedValues = [];
    var set = new Set();

    rows.forEach(function(row) {
        let key = row.join();

        if (set.has(key)) return;

        set.add(key);
        dedupedValues.push(row);

    });

    //Delete the old Sheet and insert the dedupedValues array
    sheet.clearContents();
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, dedupedValues.length, dedupedValues[0].length).setValues(dedupedValues);
}
```

If you're not comfortable with V8 you can accomplish the same thing using @Diego's solution...but with a few tweaks as follows:

```js
// ES5 version using object keys
function removeDuplicates(sheetName) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
    var rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

    var dedupedValues = [];
    var keys = {};

    rows.forEach(function(row) {
        var key = row.join();

        if (key in keys) return;

        keys[key] = true;
        dedupedValues.push(row);

    });

    //Delete the old Sheet and insert the dedupedValues array
    sheet.clearContents();
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, dedupedValues.length, dedupedValues[0].length).setValues(dedupedValues);
}
```

Comment: This question is about performance and not general alternative coding. A simple for-loop is faster than forEach for example.

Comment: The first solution in your answer is very useful if one is interested in comparing rows based upon the results of a function of the rows columns because you can maintain a set for the comparison and a set for the final output array and then regenerate the output array with a spread operator.  And then you don't have to use `dedupedValues.push(row)` You can just use `[...set]`